# String variables not being handled correctly writing to SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android and am trying to wite a simple application using SQLite to store some data. To test writing sone output data to the SQLite database, I used the following line which works fine.

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
db.addData(new datatostore("Fred", "26"));
```

I then replaced the fixed strings with string variables that I defined using an intent to pass the data between two activities and then found that the data was not written out correctly. The revised code is below.

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
Intent intent2 = getIntent();
String name = intent2.getStringExtra(TestActivity.NAME);
String age = intent2.getStringExtra(TestActivity.AGE);       
db.addData(new datatostore(name, age));
```

I can't see why this doesn't work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How are you writing in the DB??

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to post more code which shows how you're handling the write and also where you're setting the constants NAME and AGE.  You're also going to have to show us what you mean by "data was not written out correctly."  What, exactly, was written?

Comment: It would help to see just a code block of the class sending the intent this is suppose to receive.

Answer (score 0):

I think your bundle tags may not be correct.You should control them and retry.

Comment: Thanks. Just needed someone to point me to where the problem might be. On closer inspection, the bundle that I was using was incorrectly formed. Corrected it and it now works fine.